# How to generate a Program template by generating an abstract class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, abstract

i have the following problem.

The 1st step is to implement a program, which follows a specific protocol on startup.
Therefore, functions as onInit, onConfigRequest, etc. will be necessary.
(These are triggered e.g. by incoming message on a TCP Port)

My goal is to generate a class for example abstract one, which has abstract functions as onInit(), etc.
A programmer should just inherit from this base class and should merely override these abstract functions of the base class.

The rest as of the protocol e.g. should be simply handled in the background (using the code of the base class) and should not need to appear in the programmers code.

What is the correct design strategy for such tasks? and how do I deal with, that the static main method is not inheritable? What are the key-tags for this problem? (I have problem searching for a solution since I lack clear statements on this problem)

Goal is to create some sort of library/class, which - included in ones code - results in executables following the protocol.

**EDIT (new explanation):**

Okay let me try to explain more detailled:

In this case programs should be clients within a client server architecture.
We have a client server connection via TCP/IP. Each program needs to follow a specific protocol upon program start:

As soon as my program starts and gets connected to the server it will receive an Init Message (TcpClient), when this happens it should trigger the function onInit(). 
(Should this be implemented by an event system?) After onInit() a acknowledgement message should be sent to the server. Afterwards there are some other steps as e.g. a config message from the server which triggers an onConfig and so on. Let's concentrate on the onInit function.

**The idea is, that onInit (and onConfig and so on) should be the only functions the programmer should edit while the overall protocol messaging is hidden for him.**

Therefore, I thought using an abstract class with the abstract methods onInit(), onConfig() in it should be the right thing. The static Main class I would like to hide, since within it e.g. there will be some part which connects to the tcp port, which reacts on the Init Message and which will call the onInit function. 
2 problems here: 
1. the static main class cant be inherited, isn it?
2. I cannot call abstract functions from the main class in the abstract master class.

Let me give an Pseudo-example for my ideas:

```
 public abstract class MasterClass
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args){

         1. open TCP connection
         2. waiting for Init Message from server
         3. onInit();
         4. Send Acknowledgement, that Init Routine has ended successfully
         5. waiting for Config message from server
         6.....
    }

    public abstract void onInit();
    public abstract void onConfig();
}
```

I hope you get the idea now!
The programmer should afterwards inherit from this masterclass and merely need to edit the functions onInit and so on.

Is this way possible? How?
What else do you recommend for solving this?

EDIT:
The strategy ideo provided below is a good one! Check out my comment on that.

Comment: I don't fully understand your task. Please write more detailed example of you aim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this, [Strategy design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx#_self1), it may help.  A short code example below:

```
class MainClass {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
      // Where ProcessingStrategy is your abstract class.
      // SpecificProcessingStrategy is someone else's implementation.
      //
      ProcessingStrategy strategy = new SpecificProcessingStrategy();

      // Processor is implemented and provided by you and calls the appropriate methods on the 
      // ProcessingStrategy..
      // 
      Processor processor = new Processor( strategy );
      processor.Process();
   }
}
```

If you wanted to provide the Main also, then take a look at having the name of the concrete ProcessingStrategy (SpecificProcessingStrategy in this example) passed in on the command line and load it dynamically (I'm not sure how to do this in C# but I'm sure many examples on the web).

Comment: This one does work now! Cool!
Like this although the user needs to copy the above MainClass and add his own SpecificProcessingStrategy into his C# project.
Can he somehow just write SpecificProcessingStrategy and let it compile to an executable somehow using the Main function of the MainClass provided within a library? How to do so?
I really aim for that the user only needs to implement one class.(SpecificProcessingStrategy). Regards!

Comment: I am not sure how to run a Main from a library in C# (most familiar with Java) but I'm sure it is possible.  A couple of ways to accomplish the automatic loading:

1. Have the user pass in the name of the strategy class on the command line.

2. Use some sort of properties/config file that is automatically referred to by your main to load the class specified by the user.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is the Template design pattern.  Your abstract client contains the protocol details, and delegates to subclasses via protected template/hook methods to allow a conceret client to customize the behavior.

```
// In your provided library
public abstract class Client 
{
   public void Run()
   {

      OpenConnection();

      WaitForInitMsg();

      OnInit(); // notify subclass

      SendInitAckMsg();

      WaitForConfigMsg();

      OnConfig(); // notify subclass

      SendConfigAckMsg();

      // etc, etc

   }      

   protected abstract void OnInit() {}

   protected abstract void OnConfig() {}

}

// customer/client uses the functionality like this
public class ConsoleClient : Client
{
   protected void OnInit() 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Initialized");
   }

   protected void OnConfig() 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Configured");
   }

}

public class MainClass 
{    
   static void Main(string[] args)    
   {
      ConsoleClient client = new ConsoleClient();
      client.Run();
   }
}
```

The customer never has access to any internals of your Clinet object that you don't explicitly expose.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are already made a good decision in choosinhg `abstract class`. Good in it is that you can define `abstract methods` which consumer (who inherited from it) *must* override, and have also "normal" methods with code in it. In this way you create a constrains for derived type to implement several set of the functions and plus, provide it with a common set of the functions that any derived type will have by default.